# Sql Query result issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve the 2nd word on this column values but its showing Blank.

My query is:

```
select ltrim(
  substring(companyname,
  charindex(' ',companyname),
  CHARINDEX(
    ' ',
    ltrim(
      SUBSTRING(
        companyname,
        charindex(' ',companyname),
        LEN(companyname) - charindex(' ',companyname))
      )
    )
  )
)
from pmweb_companies
where companyname = '7x24 Exchange'
```

The result should return: Exchange
but it shows Blank.

Comment: What is the type of the column `companyname` ?

Comment: The datatype is nvarchar for column companyname

Comment: How about some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because that query requires the total words to be more than two, meaning you will need at least two whitespaces in the string you parse.

If you want to exclude the first word and get anything from the second word on, you can use something like this

```
select ltrim(
         substring(
           companyname,
           charindex(' ', companyname),
           len(companyname) - charindex(' ', companyname) + 1
         )
       );
```

If you want exactly the second word instead, you can hack your query into this

```
select ltrim(
  substring(companyname,
  charindex(' ', companyname),
  CHARINDEX(
    ' ',
    ltrim(
      SUBSTRING(
        companyname + ' fake',
        charindex(' ', companyname),
        LEN(companyname + ' fake') - charindex(' ', companyname))
      )
    )
  )
)
from pmweb_companies
where companyname = '7x24 Exchange'
```

**Edit**

If I understand your comment correctly, if the string has only one word, the query should return blank. If that's the case, you can use a `case` statement in your `select`

```
select  case
          when charindex(
                 ' ',
                 substring(
                   companyname,
                   charindex(' ', companyname),
                   LEN(companyname) - charindex(' ', companyname) + 1
                 )
               ) = 0 /* this means there's less than two words */
          then '' /* you can place something else here, as you prefer */
          else
            ltrim(
              substring(companyname,
              charindex(' ', companyname),
              CHARINDEX(
                ' ',
                ltrim(
                  SUBSTRING(
                    companyname + ' fake',
                    charindex(' ', companyname),
                    LEN(companyname + ' fake') - charindex(' ', companyname))
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          end
from pmweb_companies
where companyname = '7x24 Exchange'
```

Comment: The first query you posted doesn't work if the first word is not exactly 4 characters.

Comment: @SeanLange You're right, that was a typo from a test... thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi Stefano, Just wanted to update you that if the string having 2 words then the 2nd query works fine but if a column value contains only 1 word still the query returns the same 1 word but as per conditions query should check if string/column having values more than 2 words then only it should return only the 2nd word. Please input your comments.